# How to install WebSphere MQ Server?

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to create a new Queue Manager in Websphere but it does not give me a 'new option'. I only have Websphere MQ Explorer installed, how do I get the server?

Answer (score 2):

The IBM MQ Explorer is a remote administration only package which you install and configure it to point to remote queue managers to administer. It does the administration via client channels to the queue manager listeners. It does not understand how to connect to a remote machine, like ssh etc, just a remote queue manager - hence there is no way to create a queue manager on a remote machine.

If you install the MQ Explorer as a component of a server install, as part of an installation which includes the server component, then it is possible for the MQ Explorer to create new queue managers but only on the same box that MQ Explorer is running (ie locally on your box).

So to answer your question, if you only have the explorer installed you have probably installed it from:

> https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ms0t-ibm-mq-explorer

If you want to create servers from within MQ Explorer, you need to install if from the main server product as a component, so need a new installation package. The IBM MQ Advanced for Developers for example, which is freely available for developer only (ie non production only... for production use you would need to obtain licensed media):

> https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ/com.ibm.mq.helphome.doc/mq_downloads_admins.htm